# pg_restore could not execute query: ERROR: invalid locale name: "en_US.UTF-8"

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I use pg_restore on Windows 10 with a dump file made on Linux.

[image: I get this error]

I search on the web but I don't find answer.

[NEW] :
I install Ubuntu on my computer to use pg_restore but when I send

```
pg_restore -d mydatabase /home/user/Documents/dumpfile.dump
```

the command line is blocked.

Someone has this issue ?

Comment: Create the new database in UTF-8 manually before restoring, and use the pg_restore options that skip the database creation.

Answer (score 5):

Your new ubuntu installation hasn't defined the en_US.UTF-8 locale yet. So, when you're trying to restore the dumpfile, the dumpfile attempts to do something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE <database> WITH TEMPLATE = ... LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'...
```

But, 'en_US.UTF-8' is not defined by your new ubuntu server. First, you can verify this:

```
# list all "known" locales. In my case, on new Ubuntu 20, I get:
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

Edit existing `/etc/locale.gen` file, which contains the list of possible locales. Most locales will be commented out. These **will not be defined**, so, un-comment the line with 'en_US.UTF-8'.

Run (as root) locale-gen.

```
root# locale-gen
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

Notice it's now a configured locale:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

(Yes, it is lower case `utf8`, not a problem)

**Restart** your postgres server (so it sees the new locale -- you do not need to restart the ubuntu server itself), and you restore show now work.

Answer (score -3):

You will need to do some research on locales. The place to start is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html).

Postgres relies on the operating system for locale information.  The names differ between Posix and Windows.  Presumably, the simplest solution is to change the name somehow.  There might be a way to get Windows to understand the Posix names.

Comment: This might be of help: [Windows Locale names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373814(v=vs.85).aspx), although some names like 'Spanish_Spain.1252', which are *not*  two-letter codes, and are *not* dash separated (but underscore separated) , and 1252 (meaning Windows-1252 *encoding*) are commonly found.